# I/O errors, but after running badblocks everything works again : how is that possible?

Tags: io, smartctl, badblocks

**TLDR;**

HDD seemed damaged. Unable to format partition (`mkfs.ext4` I/O errors), even with a newly created GPT table. SMART test shows some errors. I was about to throw the disk away. Before that, out of curiosity, I ran a full `badblocks` test. Big surprise : it didn't detect any bad blocks ! Went back to GParted, created a GPT table + a few partitions. Everything works fine now ! What did `badblocks` do ?

**The full story**

I am trying to make sense of what just happened : I was about to throw a HDD away because I was unable to create partitions on it, and SMART showed some errors. Before throwing the disk away I just wanted to play a little with `badblocks`, and ... big surprise : `badblocks` seemed to have repaired my disk ! I didn't even know that it could do that ! So I am happy now, I can indeed use my disk, it works fine, but I am still trying to figure out what just happened !

It's a 4TB Seagate HDD that I hadn't used in a few years. I plugged it in a SATA ↔ USB adapter (adapter works fine, I use it with several other HDDs). Wirh GParted I created a new GPT partition table, and then a partition. It was unable to proceed to the end, there was a `mkfs.ext4` I/O error :

```
(...)
Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (131072 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: 0/895
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
mkfs.ext4: Input/output error while writing out and closing file system
```

I tried several times, with different USB adapters, different USB cables, different USB ports. Never worked.

I then did a SMART short test :

```
# smartctl -t short -C /dev/sde
(...)

# smartctl -a /dev/sde
(...)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short captive       Completed: read failure       90%       528         191105024
(...)
```

Obviously the HDD seems defect, right ? So I was about to throw it away, but did a `badblocks` test before :

```
# badblocks -wvs -t random -b 4096 /dev/sde
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 976754645
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

The test lasted about 19 hours (4TB disk), it didn't show any errors. I was very surprised !

Back to GParted, created a new GPT table, some partitions, everything went smooth.

I ended up doing some copy tests I am used to do, in order to check the disk's performances, and everything seems normal (155MB/s R/W when copying big files).

Also did another SMART short test, it `completed without error` this time :

```
# smartctl -t short -C /dev/sde
(...)

# smartctl -a /dev/sde
(...)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short captive       Completed without error       00%       549         -
# 2  Short captive       Completed: read failure       90%       528         191105024
(...)
```

Can someone make sense of that ? It's as if running `badblocks` somehow repaired my HDD. How is that possible ? Is `badblocks` even supposed to do that ?

Note : more info is available if needed (full SMART output and full GParted results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `badblocks` can have that effect — not really by design, but because hard drives can remap failing blocks, and will do so when they encounter a failed block during a write (since there’s no data that can be lost). By writing to every single accessible sector in the drive, `badblocks` gives ample opportunity for the drive to do so; and if the drive’s spare capacity is sufficient to remap all the failed blocks, `badblocks` won’t see anything amiss.

If you run `smartctl -a` on the drive, you should see that it has a non-zero “reallocated sector count” (attribute 5). This indicates that it has remapped sectors.

While the drive may work fine now, this does indicate that it has problems, so it should be treated with suspicion; if part of its storage has failed, more is liable to fail in the not-too-distant future.

See also [SSD: `badblocks` / `e2fsck -c` vs reallocated/remapped sectors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/756248/86440).

Comment: OK thanks, that makes sense. And yes indeed I have a raw value of 16 in `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`. So, basically, I guess that means that whenever you start to have some reallocated sectors, it's probably best to get rid of the drive. Or at least use it for unimportant stuff. Because it's a sign that it could soon fail.

Comment: As a sidenote : I usually quickly use `smartctl -H` to check if my drives are OK. But I realize now that it's not accurate at all, because it returns `PASSED` even though there are already some reallocated sectors. I think it should be more conservative and return something like 'BE CAREFUL - It works for now but could fail soon !'. It should only return `PASSED` if there is no sign of any failure at all.

Comment: @ChennyStar a non-zero relocated sector count is not necessarily indicative of a failing drive. Hard drives are manufactured with the knowledge that some sectors will likely be dead from the factory, and part of the purpose of the relocatable sector pool is to compensate for this. Thus a new, top-of-the-line hard drive can still show such a reading. However, in your case, the sectors in question worked previously, meaning they failed after you took possession of the drive, so it does more strongly imply (but still not necessitate) that the drive could have a failure in the near future.

Comment: @PixelatedFish there’s a separate attribute for thzt, the factory bad block count (189).

Comment: @PixelatedFish : I agree, it doesn't necessarily mean that the drive is going to fail. However, it means that there could a problem. This is why IMO `smartctl -H` shouldn't return `PASSED` if there are reallocated sectors, especially if those sectors are not factory dead ones. For me it's like `smartctl -H` returns a false negative : it tells me everything is OK, even though it's not. From now on I'll stop relying on `smartctl -H`'s result alone, and in case of `PASSED` I'll check some other parameters, like `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`, in order to forge my own opinion.

Comment: @StephenKitt : it seems attribute 189 is not normalized, in my case (a rather old Seagate Desktop HDD.15 ST4000DM000-1F2168) attribute 189 is `High_Fly_Writes`. I don't have anything related to factory bad blocks (all I have is attribute 183, `Runtime_Bad_Block`).

Comment: @ChennyStar you’re right, 189 is indeed not normalized, and its default mapping in Smartmontools is `High_Fly_Writes`. 189 being used for the factory bad block count seems to be specific to Crucial drives.

Comment: @PixelatedFish : in case you're interested, I found this post from a cloud company detailing which SMART attributes they are monitoring in order to take a decision about the probability of disk failure : https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-smart-stats-indicate-hard-drive-failures/. Interesting...